# Please Explain this Minimax Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I've been trying to learn how to create a tictactoe AI using the minimax method in Javascript. After watching many videos and copying the following code, I got a little confused. How does the for loop work with the minimax method that is constantly called every time. Lets say its the AI's turn, and he "plays" in the first available spot. Then the first "if" condition will be true, and the minimax method will be ran again. So how does the for loop come into play if minimax just constantly keeps getting called. Sorry if that was a little confusing, I can clarify you want me to. Thanks

```
    const moves = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < availSpots.length; i++) {
        const move = {};
        move.index = newBoard[availSpots[i]];
        newBoard[availSpots[i]] = player;

        if (player == Aiplayer) {
            const result = minimax(newBoard, huPlayer);
            move.score = result.score;
              
        } else {
            const result = minimax(newBoard, Aiplayer);
            move.score = result.score;
            
        }

        newBoard[availSpots[i]] = move.index;

        moves.push(move);

    console.log(newBoard);
    }
```

Comment: The loop does not run "constantly". Every time it's the "AI"'s turn, it will use this loop to play every move possible (in a temporary board), calculate and store the score for each possible move in the `moves` Array. You did not include it here, but I'm guessing that after this loop, there is another one that looks for the best score, and actually plays that move. On a side note, this is not AI. A real AI is not made of loops and `if` statements, it's way more complicated than that :)

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. And yes, after this, there are if statements that calculate the best score.